# Systematic validation of UX guidelines

Tags: guidelines, validation

You all probably know these kind of (ux) guidelines as listed in the post of Justin Misfud here: http://usabilitygeek.com/official-usability-user-experience-user-interface-guidelines-from-companies/

my questions are:

1. do you also have these kind of guidelines in your company or that you follow for yourself as a freelancer?
2. If yes, how do you guarantee and systematically validate that all guidelines are always respected in your work?

Comment: Your question is too open ended. Please review the [What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) section of the FAQ.

Comment: Dom, yes it's far too generic and discussion-based in it's current form. The question has been closed off to answers for now so that you can amend the question and bring it more in line with the [FAQ], at which point we'll re-open this to answers for you.

Comment: I wish I could answer this.  Seems like a perfectly fine question.  I do have those sorts of guidelines.  I have a master template that I force all designers to use.  Plus I talk to them about the patterns and importance of consistency.  There are other techniques, but this comment box is kinda small.